# Laravel insert data to multiple tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Hi I need to insert data from register form to 2 or 3 tables, users and members. I need when you click on register button to send only user id and password to users.table and the rest informations into members.table

*edit
My model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin', 'predmet', 
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

My migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('admin');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

I need cote that will import the id, predmet and name to members table

Comment: provide code which you tried

Comment: Show us what code you already have.

Comment: Yes, I did. I just need code that will send data to users and mambers at the same time.

Comment: please put member model

Answer (score 0):

First all of your field create nullable() like these

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->integer('admin')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

then in the controller

```
public function store()
{
        $user = new User;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();
        $member = new Member;
        $member->name = $request->name;
        $member->username = $request->username; 
        $member->email= $request->email; 
        $member->save();
        return back();

}
```

Comment: And then? How to send data to both tables at the same time?

Comment: i think you should read the documentation. For saving info you need to call save() method which i already mention above